# how to prove a continuous, homogeneous map between two finite dimensional vector space is linear if it is differentiable at 0.

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

By homogeneity, we can reduce the problem to a neighborhood of 0. Also, inverse function theorem tells me locally around 0, the continuous map is invertible. But I don't know how to proceed from here:

The vector spaces matters are $R^n$. But I am also interested to know if this proposition holds for general vector space and how to prove it.
And the definition of differentiablity is as follow: 
For $f: R^n\to R^m$ is differentiable at $a$  if there exists a linear transformation $R^n \to R^m$ such that $$\lim_{x\to a } \frac{|f(x)-f(a)-T(x-a)|}{|x-a|}$$ exists. 
The matrix representation of $T$ is denoted as $Df(a)$.

Comment: If you subtract the linearisation at $0$ from the original function, you'll get a continuous, homogeneous map with a $0$ derivative. Try showing that such a function must be the $0$ function.

Comment: Thanks Theo! I worked it out!

Comment: @TheoBendit Hi, I wrote up some the solutions and still find some problems. Since f is only differentiable at 0 how can we see that g is differentiable thus constant?

Comment: I would be happy to write my own answer, if you can provide me with a little more context. You say the map is between two finite-dimensional vector spaces. Since you talk about continuity or differentiability, I'm assuming this means they are real or complex spaces? Or are they just $\Bbb{R}^n$ or $\Bbb{C}^n$? Also, which definition of differentiability are you using? The result should work with Gateaux differentiability, but it would be good to match the definition used with the one you're working with.

Comment: I just added more description to the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's true for arbitrary Real Banach spaces (complete normed vector spaces) as well. The proof is shown in Loomis and Sternberg's [Advanced Calculus](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/docs/Advanced_Calculus.pdf) (page $148$, right after Theorem $7.2$)

I'll restate the argument here (but you should take a look at the example given there). The claim is:

> Let $V$ and $W$ be Real Banach spaces, and let $f:V \to W$ be a homogeneous mapping of degree $1$; i.e for all $t\in \Bbb{R}$ and for all $\xi \in V$, we have $f(t\xi) = t f(\xi)$. Lastly, suppose also that $f$ is (Frechet) differentiable at the origin $0$. Then, $f$ is linear; In fact, $f = df_0$.
>
> (I'm using $df_0$ to denote the linear map $T$ from $V$ to $W$ in your notation)

To prove this, let $\xi \in V$ be arbitrary. We'll show that $f(\xi) = df_0(\xi)$. Define the map $\gamma: \Bbb{R} \to W$ by 
\begin{align}
\gamma(t) := f(t\xi) = t f(\xi).
\end{align}
Note that $\gamma(t) = tf(\xi)$ is a linear function of $t$ and hence is differentiable at the origin (actually it's everywhere differentiable) with
\begin{align}
\gamma'(0) = f(\xi)
\end{align}
Now, we can also differentiate $\gamma(t) = f(t\xi)$ using the chain rule, because $f$ is assumed to be differentiable at the origin (see Theorem $7.2$ if you need more clarification). Doing so yields:
\begin{align}
\gamma'(0) = df_{0}(\xi)
\end{align}
Hence, we have just shown that $f(\xi) = \gamma'(0) = df_0(\xi)$. Since $\xi \in V$ was chosen arbitrarily, it follows that
\begin{align}
f = df_0
\end{align}
as claimed, thereby proving that $f$ is linear.

(I hope you realize that the differentiability assumption on $f$ at the origin is important! We have to make us of it before applying the chain rule.)

---

We can actually generalize this statement slightly and claim the following:

> Let $V,W$ be Real Banach spaces, and let $f:V \to W$ be a homogeneous function of degree $k$ (i.e for all $t \in \Bbb{R}$ and for all $\xi \in V$, $f(t\xi) = t^k f(\xi)$). If we assume in addition that $f$ is $k$ times (Frechet) differentiable at the origin, then $f$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $k$. In fact, for every $\xi \in V$, we have that
>   \begin{align}
> f(\xi) = \dfrac{1}{k!} d^kf_0(\underbrace{\xi, \dots, \xi}_{k \text{ times}})
> \end{align}

This final formula in fact shows that $f$ is a degree $k$ polynomial and hence is $C^{\infty}$. For the proof of this, see my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298741/showing-that-functional-with-continuous-partial-derivatives-is-a-quadratic-form/3298792#3298792).

Comment: Thanks! The proof looks good to me.