# Let $F: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ be smooth and such that for all $a \in \mathbb R$, $x \in \mathbb R^n$, $F(ax) = aF(x)$. Prove $F$ is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, smooth-functions, multiplicative-function

> Let $F: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ be smooth and such that for all $a \in \mathbb R$, $x \in \mathbb R^n$, $F(ax) = aF(x)$. Prove $F$ is linear.

I am sorry to say this, but I am really stuck on this problem. I tried to write $F(x + y) = 2^k F(\frac{x + y}{2^k})$ for any $k \geq 0$. Once we show the linearity for rational $n$-tuples, we would be done by smoothness. However, I am stuck on this. Can anyone help?

Comment: see [how to prove a continuous, homogeneous map between two finite dimensional vector space is linear if it is differentiable at 0.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3300966/568204).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to consider the case $m = 1$. Taking gradients, we obtain
$$
a(\nabla F)(ax) = a (\nabla F)(x)
$$
for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence
$$
(\nabla F)(ax) = (\nabla F)(x)
$$
for all $a \ne 0$. Letting $a \to 0$ gives
$$
(\nabla F)(0) = (\nabla F)(x),
$$
i.e. the gradient of $F$ is constant. It follows that $F$ is linear.

Comment: to be more explicit in the final step, constancy of the gradient implies $F$ is affine, but then homogeneity implies the additive constant must vanish, so $F$ is in fact linear.